# How do I have OpenGL Combine with Layouts?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es

So I want to either be able to have buttons and other widgets on top of my Open GL View, or I want to have my Open GL and layouts split the space of the screen. I've gotten a few answers such as creating a layout, and then having it connect from the main and set the GL Surface as a view inside the layout like:

```
myGL = new MySurface(this); 
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframelayout);
frame.addView(myGL, 0);
```

but this comes with a NullPointerException, for which it points to:

```
frame.addView(myGL, 0);
```

But, frame nor myGL is null. This is the kind of problem I've had in the past with putting certain code in the onCreate(), and is also a question I have listed on my profile(unanswered). Then I tried creating the OpenGLSurface view through the xml file as so:

```
<com.example.escape.MainActivity.MySurface
android:id="@+id/visualizer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

This also creates an error, saying:

Exception raised during rendering: loader (instance of  com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/resources/manager/ProjectClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/example/escape/MainActivity$MySurface"
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

In case you want to know: com.example.escape is the path to my MainActivity.java

I also don't want to do what others say, and create a rectangle in OpenGL that stays constantly perpendicular to the screen acting as a button.

Here's my main code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GLSurfaceView myGL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myGL=new MySurface(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}...
```

My GL Surface and Renderer Code:

```
class MySurface extends GLSurfaceView
{

private MyRenderer myRend;

public MySurface(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    myRend=new MyRenderer();
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer(myRend);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
}

Square mSquare;
float [] mViewMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mMVPMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mProjectionMatrix=new float[16];
private float[] mRotationMatrix=new float[16];

class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f);

        mSquare=new Square();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
     Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 10);

}   

}
```

Comment: Is `MySurface` defined as a local class within `MainActivity`? It doesn't look like it is from the code, but the way you use it in your layout xml (`com.example.escape.MainActivity.MySurface`), it would have to be. Also, when you tried to use `findViewById()`, did you call it after `setContentView()`?

Comment: Yes, MySurface is defined within the MainActivity, I just separated it because I wanted the code to be easier to read. As for the findViewById(), I tried it before and after setContentView(). Would it have to do with the fact that I did     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); yet I findViewById(R.id.myLayout); which is a Relative layout in my fragment_main?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I've tried putting my Surface View in a different layout other than Realtive if that mattered, but it still doesn't work.